# Read & Write Sectors in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create an application that will read a file from sectors. I found this solution in C++ http://catalog.codeproject.com/Articles/32169/FDump-Dumping-File-Sectors-Directly-from-Disk-usin but no solutions in C#. Can anyone direct me or help me create this kind of application thanks for responding.

Comment: Please note i deleted the old thread before creating this one Thanks B.

Comment: I really can't understand why you do this. You're using file system in the same way System.IO.Stream does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DeviceStream` class is not made for reading files (such as `@"\\.\PhysicalDrive1\WINDOWS\EXPLORER.EXE"`) in any sort of "raw manner".

It is meant to access a raw/physical device - such as a hard disk or cdrom device - and read/write disk blocks *below the level of the file system*.

If you use it for writing to a disk without knowing exactly what you're doing, you'll show the `C/C++` guys a whole new level of undefined behavior :) It will most likely eat your file system for lunch.